# I can't get SHA-1 Key

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, dart, sha1

When we enter the "gradle signingReport" command to get SHA-1 Key in Android Studio, we normally need to see the SHA-1 output in the console, but it gives me such an output, is there anyone who can help?

---

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCHEJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get SHA1 key by using below command.

Linux:

```
 keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Window:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Mac:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /Users/username/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: My project language is Flutter :(

Comment: yes, though you can get SHA1 key by running above command, I'm also working on flutter.

Comment: "keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: ~/.android/debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: ~/.android/debug.keystore
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:902)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:412)
        at java.base/sun.
security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:405)"   It gives the error

Comment: which os in your system i mean mac, linux or window?

Comment: os in my system windows

Comment: Please check updated answer and first verify path of `debug.keystore`

Answer (score 0):

simple use this in Windows

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```